# Maven webResources filtering on-the-fly

Tags: spring, tomcat, maven, maven-war-plugin

I'm using the maven-war-plugin to filter some resources in WEB-INF. Mostly stuff static stuff like:

```
var url = ${contextRoot}/save.json;
```

or

```
<link href="static/css/layout-${buildNumber}.css"/>
```

Everything works fantastically. My issue is that it has created a development nightmare. I typically hot deploy to a local tomcat and my IDE handles copying changes (on save) to the target directory. But when that happens I end up with a literal ${property} in my file instead of what it was originally replaced with by the war plugin. I would prefer to test view/static resource changes on-the-fly instead of having to redeploy for each change.

I've messed around with the tomcat plugin to run it but when I used that the resource filtering doesn't happen unless I use it to deploy, in which case I lose the hot-swap capabilities.

I'm using spring and I would be fine with using themes, filtering the theme properties, and then using that to replace values in my view. But what about the js/css/other static stuff?

Is there a way to have the war plugin "filter on-the-fly"? Can anyone recommend a better way accomplish what I'm trying to do? I feel like I've been looking at it for too long and have some tunnel vision on the matter.

Comment: Do you have a default profile that has those `properties` defined? Also, did you try `tomcat:run-war` you'll loose hot-swap, may be.

Comment: @Nishant Yes, there is a profile setup with the properties defined. Yes, I did try `tomcat:run-war` and I did lose hot-swap (technically, hot-swap still worked but I ended up back in my original boat, the properties weren't replaced).

Comment: that is weird. I thought using `<activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>` should work.

Comment: @Nishant. Ah. No, the activation of the profile is not my issue. By running `tomcat:run-war` everything works fine. `${contextRoot}` is replaced with `/myapp` and everything runs happily. The problem occurs when I modify that file and it reverts back to `${contextRoot}`. Again, everything works fine if I'm just running once or deploying. But if I want to actively work on the project (i.e. modify a file then refresh the page to see the results), the filtering doesn't work. Which makes sense. I just want to know if there is a way around it.

Comment: well. I use Jetty in dev envt (and Tomcat in prod) and I get properties filtered correctly and dynamically. I think you do not have much choice other than one of these http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html sorry.

Comment: Netbeans. But I'll get the same behavior without it (cmd line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I kept the same methods but changed my approach to accomplish this.

For Javascript, I put anything that needs to be filtered into a single Constants file:

```
// Constants.js

var BASE_URL = '${contextRoot}';
```

The reason behind this is that the `Constants.js` file will very rarely be modified and avoid the problem of having that file redeployed on the fly.

My other example was using `${buildNumber}` to avoid browser resources caching across deploys. I found that appending the build number to a query string worked just as well:

```
<link href="static/css/layout.css?${buildNumber}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use eclipse with m2e and m2e-wtp, you can get on-the-fly web resource filtering.
This is explained here : https://community.jboss.org/en/tools/blog/2011/05/03/m2eclipse-wtp-0120-new-noteworthy

And demoed there : http://bit.ly/wGcD4j

Note that, in this video, the Maven Profile Management UI is coming from JBoss Tools 3.3.0.Beta1 (http://docs.jboss.org/tools/whatsnew/maven/maven-news-3.3.0.Beta1.html)